# Create parent/child slider set in MAYA Attribute Editor

Tags: python, callback, maya

I am trying to create a slider setup for an Attribute Editor view.  I know I have to setup a callback but have been stumpt.  The goal is to have a parent slider with two children.  The purpose is for pose control is when you have, ie, both arms going up for the parent and individual controls to each arm being the children.  I have been able to do this if I create a UI window but have not been able to get it to work as an AE template.
This is the code that works for the UI window.

```
class frGUI(object):
    def add_sliders(self, *_):
        # The test sliders
        self.parentval[0] = 0
        self.slider[0] = pm.floatSliderGrp(l='Up-Down', p=self.frame1111, f=True, min=-100.0, max=100.0,
                                           v=0.0, cc=lambda *_: self.update_children(0, 1, 2),
                                           dc=lambda *_: self.update_children(0, 1, 2))
        self.offsetval[1] = 0
        self.slider[1] = pm.floatSliderGrp(l='Up-Down Left', p=self.frame1111, f=True, min=-100.0, max=100.0,
                                           v=0.0, cc=lambda *_: self.update_child_offset(0, 1),
                                           dc=lambda *_: self._up_down_left())
        self.offsetval[2] = 0
        self.slider[2] = pm.floatSliderGrp(l='Up-Down Right', p=self.frame1111, f=True, min=-100.0, max=100.0,
                                           v=0.0, cc=lambda *_: self.update_child_offset(0, 2),
                                           dc=lambda *_: self._up_down_right())
    def __init__(self):
        self.parentval = {}
        self.offsetval = {}
        self.slider = {}
        if pm.window('mainwindow', exists=True):
            pm.deleteUI('mainwindow')
        self.window = pm.window('mainwindow', title='Test Rig', w=425, h=600, mxb=False, mnb=True)
        pm.scrollLayout()
        # First-level tabs
        tab1 = pm.tabLayout(w=405, h=600, imw=5, imh=5)
        # First second-level tab
        form111 = pm.formLayout()
        pm.frameLayout(w=385, lv=False)
        self.frame1111 = pm.frameLayout(lv=False, bv=True)
        pm.setParent('..')
        pm.setParent('..')
        pm.setParent('..')
        pm.tabLayout(tab1, edit=True, tabLabel=((form111, 'Test')))
        self.add_sliders(self)
        pm.showWindow(self.window)

    def _up_down(self, *_):
        self._up_down_left()
        self._up_down_right()

    def _up_down_left(self, *_):
        self.update_lShldrBend()

    def _up_down_right(self, *_):
        self.update_rShldrBend()

    def update_lShldrBend(self, *_):
        value = pm.floatSliderGrp(self.slider[1], q=True, v=True)
        pm.setAttr('lShldrBend.rotateZ', value)

    def update_rShldrBend(self, *_):
        value = pm.floatSliderGrp(self.slider[2], q=True, v=True)*(-1)
        pm.setAttr('rShldrBend.rotateZ', value)

    def update_children(self, parent, child1, child2, *_):
        child1lab = pm.floatSliderGrp(self.slider[child1], q=True, l=True)
        child2lab = pm.floatSliderGrp(self.slider[child2], q=True, l=True)
        child1par = pm.floatSliderGrp(self.slider[child1], q=True, p=True)
        child2par = pm.floatSliderGrp(self.slider[child2], q=True, p=True)
        child1min = pm.floatSliderGrp(self.slider[child1], q=True, min=True)
        child2min = pm.floatSliderGrp(self.slider[child2], q=True, min=True)
        pm.deleteUI(self.slider[child1])
        pm.deleteUI(self.slider[child2])
        self.parentval[parent] = pm.floatSliderGrp(self.slider[parent], q=True, v=True)
        child1val = self.offsetval[child1] + self.parentval[parent]
        child2val = self.offsetval[child2] + self.parentval[parent]
        self.slider[child1] = pm.floatSliderGrp(l=child1lab, p=child1par, f=True, min=child1min, max=100.0,
                                                v=child1val, cc=lambda *_: self.update_child_offset(0, 1),
                                                dc=lambda *_: self._up_down_left(1))
        self.slider[child2] = pm.floatSliderGrp(l=child2lab, p=child2par, f=True, min=child2min, max=100.0,
                                                v=child2val, cc=lambda *_: self.update_child_offset(0, 2),
                                                dc=lambda *_: self._up_down_right(2))
        if parent == 0:
            self._up_down()

    def update_child_offset(self, parent, child, *_):
        childval = pm.floatSliderGrp(self.slider[child], q=True, v=True)
        self.offsetval[child] = childval - self.parentval[parent]
        if child == 1:
            self._up_down_left()
        elif child == 2:
            self._up_down_right()

import maya.cmds as cmds
import pymel.core as pm

example = frGUI()
```

I'm new to MAYA coding on this level but have done a fare bit elsewhere.

Comment: Did you already try anything to add it to the AttributeEditor?

Comment: I have tried to use the Attribute Editor Template Builder but couldn't get it to work.  I know if I refer to a callback in the template it has to exist to get the template to load.  I tried to put a print statement in the callback to see if it was actually being executed and got nothing back on the console so I don't even know if I have that setup right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a node template with pymel like this:

```
import pymel.core as pm
    
class BaseTemplate(pm.ui.AETemplate):
    
    def addControl(self, control, label=None, **kwargs):
        pm.ui.AETemplate.addControl(self, control, label=label, **kwargs)
        
    def beginLayout(self, name, collapse=True):
        pm.ui.AETemplate.beginLayout(self, name, collapse=collapse)

class AEmyownNodeTemplate(BaseTemplate):
    def __init__(self, nodeName):
        BaseTemplate.__init__(self,nodeName)
        self.thisNode = None
        self.ksrType = None
        self.node = pm.PyNode(self.nodeName)
        self.buildBody(nodeName)        
   
    def buildMyOwnTemplates(self, nodeName):
        self.thisNode = pm.PyNode(nodeName)
        if self.thisNode.type() in ['mesh']:
            self.beginLayout("MyOwnLayout" ,collapse=1)
            self.endLayout()
    
    def buildBody(self, nodeName):
        self.buildMyOwnTemplates(nodeName)
```

Let's say it it saved somewhere in the pythonpath as aeNodeTemplate.py then you can use it together with a callback in userSetup:

```
import pymel.core as pm
import aeNodeTemplate

pm.callbacks(addCallback=aeNodeTemplate.AEmyownNodeTemplate, hook='AETemplateCustomContent', owner="me")
```

This should work for all mesh nodes where a new layout named `MyOwnLayout` should appear.

Comment: So, I put the python code in a file aeNodeTemplate.py in my "Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/scripts/AETemplaes" directory.  I then added the callback code to my userSetup.py file in my "My Documents/maya/2028/scripts" directory.  I don't see anything new when I create, for instance, a sphere.  I'm not sure where the new layout should appear.

Comment: It should appear in the attribute editor.

Comment: I must have done something wrong because I don't see any change in the attribute editor.  I open a fresh maya screen, create a sphere, click on the shape node but do not see anything new in the attribute editor.

Comment: For testing I placed both scripts (userSetup.py and aeNodeTemplate.py) in users maya2023/scripts directory and it works fine. If is does not appear, you could have a look at the output windows if you see an error message. I edited the userSetup.py above to include the import statements which work in my maya.

Comment: The import statements fixed the problem, I can now see "MyOwnLayout" in the AE.  I have not been able to add anything into the new section let alone get the parent child slider setup in my original post.